# Pandas GroupBy Concatenation Issues

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data table that contains
NAME, DATE, TYPE, VALUE A, VALUE B, VALUE C, ....

Theoretically the NAME, DATE, TYPE are supposed to be unique, but it turns out they are not, so I need to figure out how to handle it.

Example Input:

```
Bob, 1/1/18, AType, blah, test, test2
Bob, 1/1/18, AType, blah2, test, test2
Bob, 1/1/18, BType, blah, test, test2
```

Ideal Output

```
Bob, 1/1/18, AType, [blah,blah2], test, test2
Bob, 1/1/18, BType, blah, test, test2
```

My goal is to merge the VALUE A values into a JSON style array, and then take the last value for VALUE B and VALUE C.

I have tried:

```
data.groupby('NAME', 'DATE', 'TYPE').apply(lambda x: ','.join(set(x)))
```

But that merges ALL of the fields....  Or seems to.

Any help?

Comment: Why isn't the first line's output `..., AType, [blah,blah2],[test,test],[test2,test2]`? I guess because duplicates? But will `blah2` always be similar to `blah` in some way?

Comment: Because I only want to keep the multiple values for VALUE A, I only want the last value for VALUE B and VALUE C even if there are more than one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['Bob', '1/1/18', 'AType', 'blah', 'test', 'test2'],
                   ['Bob', '1/1/18', 'AType', 'blah2', 'test', 'test3'],
                   ['Bob', '1/1/18', 'BType', 'blah', 'test', 'test2']],
                  columns=['NAME', 'DATE', 'TYPE', 'VALUE A', 'VALUE B', 'VALUE C'])

f = {'VALUE A': lambda x: set(x), 'VALUE B': 'last', 'VALUE C': 'last'}

df = df.groupby(['NAME', 'DATE', 'TYPE'])['VALUE A', 'VALUE B', 'VALUE C']\
       .agg(f).reset_index()
df['VALUE A'] = df['VALUE A'].map(list)

#   NAME    DATE   TYPE        VALUE A VALUE B VALUE C
# 0  Bob  1/1/18  AType  [blah2, blah]    test   test3
# 1  Bob  1/1/18  BType         [blah]    test   test2
```

Comment: The issue with that is that it also groups by the other values, which I don't want to do.  I just want to take the value from the last one for VALUE B and VALUE C.

Comment: @user3507901. Sorry, I don't understand. Can you provide an example of input/output to demonstrate when my solution breaks, as it seems to match your expected output?

Comment: Change the test2 to test3 in the second AType... it yields three results but should only yield 2.

Comment: Awesome!... THANKS